# stream Mac audio via bluetooth to my hearing aid

Tags: bluetooth

My hearing aid receives bluetooth audio from my iPhone (bluetooth LEA), but not from my Mac. I watch all films on the computer screen, but want the audio-channel to be streamed to my hearing aid. Can I tunnel the iphone?

Comment: It would likely be helpful to add the make and model of the hearing aid as well as the iPhone model and iOS version to your question.

Comment: Signia Active Pro and iPhone 12 Pro